# Selecting a phonebook's contact from populated listview

Tags: android, sms, contacts, android-contacts

Hi i have the following code which is basically populating a list of the phone's contact and display it on a list view.

```
listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // GET PHONE BOOK'S CONTENT
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String [] entries = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID
        };

        int [] temp = {
                android.R.id.text1,
                android.R.id.text2
        };

        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                cursor, entries, temp);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        if(listView != null){
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.w("TAG", "SELECTING: " + listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());

                    /*
                    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.fromParts("sms", listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(), null));
                    i.putExtra("sms_body", "Some message goes here.");
                    i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                    startActivity(i);
                    */
                }
            });
        }
```

What i would like to do is to output the name of the contact along with the associated phone number (primary number). So that i can create a new intent where an sms text message has been pre-defined based on the phone number and the name of my contact.

Can any one show me how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

```
    ArrayList<String> listOfName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listOfNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.PHOTO_ID);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
            listOfName.add(name);
            listOfNumber.add(phoneNumber);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfName);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String selectedFromList =(String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think you misunderstood what i mean. I am trying to output (i.e. display it on Logcat) the NAME and the PHONE NUMBER of the item clicked on the listview.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to just put this line in your (list on item click lisetener):

```
Log.w("TAG", "SELECTING: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

INSTEAD OF

```
Log.w("TAG", "SELECTING: " + listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());
```

---

```
                               **Edited**
```

---

*To achieve what you were asking can be done in following way:*

Make a SetterGetter Class and put this things in that Instead of putting in [String array].

```
String [] entries = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}
```

Then Make an ArrayList of that Setter-Getter Class and **Add** all that Setter-Getter Class in this ArrayList after filling them with data.

Pass this ArrayList to Adapter Class.

And in your OnItemClickListener you can have your phone & Name like this:

```
Your_ArrayList.get(position).getName();
Your_ArrayList.get(position).getPhoneNumber();
```

And you are done.
Its difficult to understand but If you try to make a StepByStep implementation I mentioned, you will get your goal.

Comment: Hi, the solution you suggest works similarly to mine. What i am trying to do is instead of getting the contact as an Object, i would like to get the Name (String) and the Phone number (String) of that Object.